# Call javascript from another window to main [node-webkit]

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

From point to another:

```
var win = gui.Window.get(window.open('index2.html'));
win.eval(null, 'alert("Alert from second window!");');
```

But cause call javascript of the second window in the main?

Comment: Unfortunately your English skills need to be better to use this website. I can _sort of_ see what you're getting at, but it's still very ambiguous.

Comment: My english is ochen horosho

Comment: Нет, на самом деле это не.

Comment: Your russian too not very good. Google translate good thing, but translation is not correct

Comment: If you didn't use Google translate for your question, try it. It might make more sense to native English speakers ;).

Comment: Can you clarify what you're desired behavior is, and what is happening currently? Its a little unclear from your code excerpt what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I think i understand what he wants to do. Basically he has a original page, and from this page (lets call it original) wants to open another url (index2.html) and execute a javascript function in index2.html. Questions: index2.html is already opened or must be "started". And the function you want to execute, is it already defined in that page or do you want to execute any javascript code u want in that page?

Comment: Im no expert in node-webkit but for security reasons i think you are not able to do what you want. Imagine what could you do with money related websites.